# Binding MediaElement to slider position

Tags: wpf, binding, mediaelement

I have MediaElement and Slider. How I can bind MediaElement.Position to Slider.Value without DispatcherTimer?

Answer (score 1):

OK SO this *COULD* be that :

```
<Slider 
    x:Name="PositionSlider"  
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="{Binding 
                  ElementName=mediaElement,  
                  Path=mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}"   
 />

<MediaElement 
    x:Name="mediaElement"
    Position="{Binding Value, 
               ElementName=PositionSlider, 
               Converter={StaticResource MyMsToTimeSpanConverter}}"  />
```

!! BUT !! Position is not a dependency property, so you cannot do any binding on it. When you say 'it doesn't work' ... SURE it doesn't, and it never will. binding requires dependency properties.

So you should do like Microsoft does for its MediaElement small demo : handle everything in code behind.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748248.aspx

Comment: Yes. I put  Minimum="0"                                          Maximum="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement, Path=mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan.TotalMilliseconds}" , but     Value="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement, Path=Position.TotalMilliseconds}" - I can't put TotalMilliseconds, because it doesn't work with read-only TotalMilliseconds...          Can you explain me what I must do?

Comment: And if i set Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement, Path=mediaElement.NaturalDuration.TimeSpan}" Value="{Binding ElementName=mediaElement, Path=Position, Mode=TwoWay}" - it did not work((

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong question. I want that the Thumb of Slider also changed it own position,when mediaElement playing

Comment: OK. But now since you don't want to use timers, how would you do that ? maybe using the LayoutUpdated event to refresh the Slider... *maybe* ok for movies but not for music... But why not a timer by the way ? like 5 times a second it won't slow down the application...

Comment: I do this on my notebook it is good, but battery dont work and sometimes playing works bad. Do you think this happend because battery don't work?