# Bind Media Element and Slider

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

So i have a Media Element and a Slider 
and i want to bind the Position property of **MediaElement** to the **slider** in ViewModel

Like:-

```
<Slider 
    x:Name="PositionSlider"  
    Minimum="0" 
    Maximum="{Binding Position,Mode=TwoWay"/>

<MediaElement 
    x:Name="mediaElement"
    Position="{Binding Position,Mode=TwoWay"/>
```

but i cannot `bind position of the media element since it's not a dependency property`.

is there any alternative to achieve this?

Comment: you can implement an attached property that is boundable, that changes the position of the media element when its value is changed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding MediaElement to slider position](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11808108/binding-mediaelement-to-slider-position)

Comment: i saw answer to that question it suggested to do in code behind but i want do it in MVVM

Comment: @EladKatz how?? could you share a sample

Comment: had some free time at work so i wrote it for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can implement an attached property that is boundable, that changes the position of the media element when its value is changed.

The Attached Property is defined as follows:

```
public class MediaElementExtension
{


    public static TimeSpan GetBindablePosition(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (TimeSpan)obj.GetValue(BindablePositionProperty);
    }

    public static void SetBindablePosition(DependencyObject obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(BindablePositionProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for BindablePosition.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindablePositionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BindablePosition", typeof(TimeSpan), typeof(MediaElementExtension), new PropertyMetadata(new TimeSpan(), BindablePositionChangedCallback));

    private static void BindablePositionChangedCallback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MediaElement mediaElement = d as MediaElement;
        if (mediaElement == null) return;

        mediaElement.Position = (TimeSpan)e.NewValue;
    }


}
```

And now you can use it as follows:

```
<MediaElement local:MediaElementExtension.BindablePosition="{Binding SomePropertyFromViewModel}"   />
```

Comment: The property does not get changed from the media element although when changed from the slider it works fine. and the seeking looks very slow. i have implemented this using storyboard but i wanted to do the same with the Position property!! Anyways thanks a ton for your guidance and effort:)